# Calculate value of radiobutton

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a calculate form with checkboxes and radio. If element is checked (selected) - I sum it value to constant.

For checkboxes I use this code:

```
   var normochas = 0;
   function Count(a,b) {
    if(a==1) {
        normochas = normochas + b;
        $('#sidebar-contact .blue').text(normochas);
    } else {
        normochas = normochas - b;
       $('#sidebar-contact .blue').text(normochas);
    }
   }

$(':checkbox').change(function () {
    var count = parseInt($(this).val());
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
        Count(1,count);
        return;
    }
    Count(0,count);
 });
```

How to do this for radio? I want, if you select item 1 and then select item 2 - js **MINUS** from `normochas` value of item 1 and **PLUS** value of item 2 to `normochas`.

```
<ul>
<li><input type="radio" name="cms" value="5" /> Item 1</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="cms" value="13" /> Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Usually there can only be one radio selected, that's why is a radio...I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you want the radio button marked "Item 1" to have its value subtracted, is there any reason you can't just make it a negative number?

Answer (score 3):

you can calculate their values this way:

```
$("input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){

    var radios = 0;
    var checkboxes = 0;

    $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function(){
        radios += parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
        checkboxes += parseInt($(this).val());
    });

   alert(radios + checkboxes);

});
```